# How to get detail information about AGSFeature layer in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, arcgis

I'm able to add 3 layers on basemap from arcgis iOS sdk. Now I want to get detail information from feature layer. Can anyone help me. And sometimes data is populated on map but sometimes it take too much time to load. Below is my code from which I'm able to add 3 feature layers on basemap.

```
// Add basemap.
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_map/mapserver"];
AGSTiledMapServiceLayer* layer = [AGSTiledMapServiceLayer tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL: url];
layer.delegate = self;
[self.mapView addMapLayer:layer withName:@"Streets"];

//zoom to an area
AGSEnvelope *envelope = [AGSEnvelope envelopeWithXmin:-1.34732920649E7 ymin:4533851.309500001 xmax:-1.3431785844E7
```

ymax:4641521.468800001  spatialReference:self.mapView.spatialReference];
    [self.mapView zoomToEnvelope:envelope animated:NO];

```
// Structures.
NSString *urlString = [self.currentWorkOrder.detectionURL substringToIndex:[self.currentWorkOrder.detectionURL length]-1];

self.featureLayerURL0 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0",urlString]];

self.featureLayer0 = [AGSFeatureLayer featureServiceLayerWithURL:self.featureLayerURL0 mode:AGSFeatureLayerModeOnDemand];
self.featureLayer0.delegate = self;
[self.mapView addMapLayer:self.featureLayer0 withName:@"CloudData0"];

// Alignment.
self.featureLayerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@1",urlString]];

self.featureLayer = [AGSFeatureLayer featureServiceLayerWithURL:self.featureLayerURL mode:AGSFeatureLayerModeOnDemand];
self.featureLayer.delegate = self;
[self.mapView addMapLayer:self.featureLayer withName:@"CloudData"];

// Detections.
self.featureLayerURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@2",urlString]];

self.featureLayer1 = [AGSFeatureLayer featureServiceLayerWithURL:self.featureLayerURL1 mode:AGSFeatureLayerModeOnDemand];
self.featureLayer1.delegate = self;
PO(self.featureLayer1.fields);
[self.mapView addMapLayer:self.featureLayer1 withName:@"CloudData1"];
```

Please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a network for which it too much time to load the layers on map. Now able to get details of each layer from AGSCalloutDelegate methods

```
  - (void)didClickAccessoryButtonForCallout:(AGSCallout *)callout
    {
        NSLog(callout.representedFeature);
    }
```